# NestJS + Apollo Federation Gateway Save Schema

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-federation

### Question

When making the Apollo Gateway leveraging the NestJS GraphQL Module, how can you save the schema file?

### Background

Normally with NestJS GraphQL support you can save the schema file with something like this.

```js
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloFederationDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
      autoSchemaFile: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), './schema.gql'),
        federation: 2
      },
      playground: true
    }),
```

However, it seems like for the Gateway it seems like the `autoSchemaFile` is specifically excluded. So how can I save the schema?

I'm developing within a mono-repo with code generation, so ideally I store the schema so that I can directly reference the schema file when generating clent side code.

### Things I've Tried

#### Generated the Schema Manually

I've tried to get the Schema after the app has initialized as shown below. However the code below produces the error attached.

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { GraphQLSchemaHost } from '@nestjs/graphql';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  await app.listen(3002);

  const { schema } = app.get(GraphQLSchemaHost);
}
bootstrap();
```

```
Error: GraphQL schema has not yet been created. Make sure to call the "GraphQLSchemaHost#schema" getter when the application is already initialized (after the "onModuleInit" hook triggered by either "app.listen()" or "app.init()" method).
```

I also tried the approach of adding `onModuleInit` to `app.module` however, the same error is produced making me think that the schema is generated later with the Gateway then in normal GraphQL drivers.

### Additional Information

#### Current GraphQL Gateway Config

```js
GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<ApolloGatewayDriverConfig>({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      driver: ApolloGatewayDriver,
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        gateway: {
          supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
            subgraphs: [
              { name: 'service_1', url: configService.getOrThrow('service_1.uri') },
              { name: 'service_2', url: configService.getOrThrow('service_2.uri') },
            ]
          })
        }
      })
    })
```